# Copy text to clipboard from a specific data cell in a table.

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I am trying to use a JavaScript Function in my php file to copy data from specific cells in the table. Each row has a column for Project, Description and link to the project.

I want to be able to copy the the links to my clipboard on a button click.  However, no matter what row I click to copy the link, it only copies the last one.

My Javascript function only takes in the last ID variable that was displayed on the table, and not the ID of the variable i wanted to copy...

```
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
                echo '<tr align="center">
                        <td>'.$row["pid"].':<br>'.$row["pname"].'</td>
                        <td>' .$row["URLdescription"].'</td>
                        <td>
                                <input type="text" value="'.$row['directionsURL'].'" id="'.$id.'">
                                <button onclick="myFunction()" name="copy"> Copy </button>
                        </td>
                     </tr>';
    };   //  END WHILE
```

^^ this is my while loop

```
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
          var copyText = document.getElementById("<?php echo $id; ?>")
          copyText.select();
          document.execCommand("copy");
          alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
        }
</script>
```

^^here's my JavaScript function.

Comment: I got the script from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp)

Comment: `var copyText = document.getElementById("<?php echo $id; ?>")`.  This is always going to look at the same element.  You want to pass the id to the function.

Comment: "I got the script from w3schools"  Burn it to the ground and start over.

Comment: @PatrickQ Do you actually have a good reason or are you just following the hipe train? W3Schools used to be a bad resource, but it progresed far enough over the years that it's definitely reliable enough for beginners. Go ahead and try to find a page on it where it's incorrect. You'll find it quite challenging.

Comment: @icecub https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: @icecub I encounter far more people having trouble with something who said they learned it from w3schools or were following a guide from there than from _any_ other resource.  Has it improved, maybe.  But that's not saying much.  When you don't know what you're doing, and don't know any better, you should stay as far away as possible from anywhere with a track record like theirs.

Comment: @PatrickQ It's not my intention to start a discussion about it. I just believe it's a bit unfair to judge someone or something on its past instead of its present. I'm not saying W3Schools is flawless. It sure isn't. Like Chris just gave an example. I'm just saying it's _mostly_ good enough for beginners. Mentioning W3Schools is enough to judge something to be flawed instead of verifying it first. And that's just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can clean up that loop a bit:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   extract($row);
   echo "<tr align='center'>
       <td>$pid:<br>$pname</td>
       <td>$URLdescription</td>
       <td>
           <input type='text' value='$directionsURL'>
           <button class='copy'> Copy </button>
       </td>
   </tr>";
};   //  END WHILE
```

By wrapping the string in double quotes `"`, you can use variables inside it. We get those from calling `extract()` on the row array.

Next, we assign the click handlers to the buttons:

```
// get all buttons, turn NodeList into Array
const buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".copy"));

// click handler
const handleCopyClick = evt => {
  // grab the <input> via button's parent <td>
  var input = evt.target.parentNode.querySelector('input');
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  input.blur(); // remove selection
};

// finally, assign the function as handler for each button
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleCopyClick);
});
```

Finally, if those `<input>`s are only `<input>`s because you need that for the clipboard functionality, you should probably use a hidden input and show the URL using a `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<input type="text" value="
<?php echo $row['account']; ?>" id="
<?php echo "myInput".$id ;?>"> 
            
<button class = "abc btn-sm btn-success" data-id1="
    <?php echo "myInput".$id ;?>">
            Copy
            
</button>
```

JS

```
  $(document).on('click', '.abc', function(){  
    var id = $(this).data("id1");
            
    var copyText = document.getElementById(id);

    /* Select the text field */
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

    /* Copy the text inside the text field */
    document.execCommand("copy");

    /* Alert the copied text */
     alert("Copy: " + copyText.value);

});
```